# Generate random number in given range from random bytes

Tags: algorithm, random, cryptography, numeric-ranges

There are similar questions, but most of them too language specific. I'm looking for a general solution. Given some way to produce *k* random bytes and a number *n*, I need to produce a random number in range *1...n* (inclusive).

What I've come up with so far:

1. To determine the number of bytes needed to represent *n*, calculate

`f(n):=ceiling(ln(n)/8ln(2))=ceiling(0.180337*ln(n))`

2. Get a random number in range in range *1...2^8f(n)* for 0-indexed bytes b[i]:

`r:=0
 for i=0 to k-1:
   r = r + b[i] * 2^(8*i)
 end for`

3. To scale to *1...n* without bias:

   `R(n,r) := ceiling(n * (r / 256^f(n)))`

But I'm not sure this does not create a bias or some subtle one-off error. Could you check whether this sound and/or make suggestions for improvements? Is this the right way to do this?

In answers, please assume that there are no modular bit-twiddling operations available, but you can assume arbitrary precision arithmetics. (I'm programming in Scheme.)

*Edit: There is definitely something wrong with my approach, because in my tests rolling a dice yielded a few cases of 0! But where is the error?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is similar to what you'd do if you wanted to generate a number from 1 to n from a random floating point number from 0 to 1, inclusive. If `r` is the random float:

```
result = (r * n) + 1
```

If you have arbitrary precision arithmetic, you can compute `r` by dividing your k-byte integer by the maximum value expressible in `k` bytes, + 1.

So if you have 4 bytes `87 6F BD 4A`, and `n` = 200:

```
((0x876FBd4A/0x100000000) * 200) + 1
```